# Hibernate NullPointerException In Loader Class

Tags: hibernate, db2

I'm having a bit of an odd problem.  This is Hibernate 3.3.2-GA with DB2400Dialect.  I'm seeing the following exception --

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:720)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:312)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1723)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:175)
at com.example.WidgetDao.getAllWidgets(WidgetDao.java:28)
at com.example.TestWidgetDao.testGetAllWidgets(TestWidgetDao.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:35)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

The testGetAllWidgets() method is calling WidgetDao.getAllWidgets() twice in a row.  The first call works perfectly fine.  The result set and mapped objects returned are exactly as I expect.  However, I call getAllWidgets() immediately again and the above NPE is thrown.  I've tracked it down a bit deeper and the following line in Loader.java is returning a null result set --

```
// Line 1809 in     
rs = session.getBatcher().getResultSet( (CallableStatement) st, dialect );
```

The DAO method is executed a stored procedure defined via  in the mapping document.

I'm really stumped here.  I've literally mapped a few dozen classes to different stored procedures.  Suddenly this one has decided to give me fits.  There's nothing special about the proc and it simply returns a few String columns.

Anyone have an idea how to track this down further?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is more likely then not a problem with DB2 JDBC driver.

Put a breakpoint in `DB2Dialect.getResultSet()` method and check the `ResultSet` you're getting there. Perhaps it's trying to be smart and cache the `CallableStatement` and something goes awry.

When you say "call it immediately again" do you really mean "immediately" - e.g. within the same session? Does it work in a new session (it should)? If you don't find a JDBC-level solution (some connection parameter to turn caching off), that maybe an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll dig into that.  

Immediate is immediate!!  Here's the exact code.  I've also tried different sessions and it still fails exactly the same way.

    @Test
    public void testGetAllWidgets() {
        // ThreadLocal sessions
        Session s = SessionFactory.currentSession();
        WidgetDao dao = new WidgetDao(s);

        List widgets = dao.getAllWidgets();  // Works
        widgets = dao.getAllWidgets();  // Vomits

        SessionFactory.closeSession();
    }

Comment: I've done as suggested and put a break in Db2Dialect.getResultSet().  Sure enough, the first time through ResultSet rs = ps.getResultSet(); returns a valid set.  2nd time it returns null.

Comment: Are you using a DB pool with more than one connection? If you are and this fails with different sessions, this must be a bug in JDBC (I don't think callable statement can be cached across connections). Are you using the latest and greatest jdbc version? Are there any bug reports for it?

Comment: Either a JDBC bug or Hibernate.  I'm using the latest JTOPEN driver and Hibernate 3.3.2-GA.  I may try a dev build of Hibernate.  I'm using pooling but have stripped that out to simplify the problem.  It's still there.  No difference if pooling is in or out.

Comment: The reason I've mentioned pooling is because there's potentially a difference between doing this on the same connection vs different connections (apparently, neither works in your case so ignore that). Anyway, this is definitely not a Hibernate core bug. Either it's a JDBC problem (most likely) or the way `Db2Dialect` deals with `CallableStatement` is not applicable to this particular JDBC driver. Have you tried doing this in straight-up JDBC? Should be reasonably trivial to throw together a test case. If it still fails, submit a bug to JTOpen.